# SQL Server error : the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have used identity server database for my project with membership. It is working fine. Now I connected new server with new database getting error. If use the old server means it is running without error. How to clear this? Can I set any property to new database?

```
MembershipUser membershipObj = Membership.GetUser(Context.User.Identity.Name.ToString());
```

`membershipObj` getting this error

> Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=1764; handshake=13233;

Comment: I found this checklist to be useful:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7168/30711

Answer (score -1):

1. Enable necessary protocols (TCP/Named Pipes) in SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. Explicitly allow connections (and/or ports) in Windows Firewall (Server's)

These fixed my issue. Hope it helps some body.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what playing with windows firewall is?

Comment: @PratikBhavsar Unless the firewalls are properly configured, you may not be able to _talk_ to the SQL Server properly.